# Make bigger the hotSpot of the cursor using c#

Tags: c#

I need to make bigger the range of the hotspot cursor.

e.g. change the cursor to a square of 100x100 and everything inside the square can be click able, not just only 1 pixel.

Is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: What does cab be clickable mean. If theresmore than one which one has been clicked on?

Answer (score 1):

using the default windows shell (ie, desktop), no. Windows cursors requre a single pixel as the hotspot so that it's easy for the OS to know what *exactly* has been clicked. You could go down the route of implementing your own desktop and cursor system but this is overkill and you will still have the problem of figuring out what has been clicked within a 100x100 square. It'd be quite easy for a text box and a button to be within 100 pixels of each other

Comment: more 'impractical'. Why are you trying to do this? Perhaps there's a simpiler alternative

Comment: i making this for handicap people, so they can use the pointer in applications made for them. They cant move the mouse to a precise point because it is so small, so making it bigger could help them.

Comment: @FernandoSantiago the more usual way of solving this is to use the accessibility features of windows itself, specifically the Magnifier tool. This simply displaying a window that shows a magnified section of the screen at the same point as the cursor